# Delete current element jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, element

I have "dinamic" accordion. Click on "addBtn" creates new element. Each element has button "delete" which deletes current element.

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">

                        <div id="aE">
                            <div id="aT" class="aT_val"> 
                                <h3></h3>
                            </div>

                            <div id="aC" class="aC_val">
                                <p></p>
                            </div>

                            <div id="deleteBtn" class="deleteBtn"><img src="images/del.png"></div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#addBtn').click(function() {
        count++;

        $('#accordion').append('<div id="aE' + count + '"><div id="aT' + count + '" class="aT_val"><h3></h3></div><div id="aC' + count + '" class="aC_val"><p></p></div><div id="deleteBtn' + count + '" class="deleteBtn"><img src="images/delete-button.png"></div></div>'); });

$('#deleteBtn' + count).click(function() {
        $('#aE' + count).remove();
    });
```

But "deleteBtn" doesn't delete element "aE". How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

`'#aE' + count` is being evaluated on the click, not as the function is created, hence it will be the last used value of `count` and not the value when the button was made.

Answer (score 0):

the onclick callback for #deleteBtn is being evaluated in difference context from the parent scope.

```
$('#deleteBtn' + count).click(function() {
    // this will always return a fixed number
    $('#aE' + count).remove();
});
```

Try this

```
$('#deleteBtn' + count).click(function() {
    // this will return a correct id
    var cnt =  this.id.replace('deleteBtn', '');
    $('#aE' + cnt ).remove();
});
```

Comment: or more simply $(this).parent('div').remove();

Comment: I think `$(this)` or `#deleteBtn` that you referred to is a child element of `#aE`.

Comment: men, $(this).parent('div').remove(); works but only without "count". Like this $('#deleteBtn').click(function() {
   $(this).parent('div').remove()
  });